# getElementById does not work in IE if NAME attribute is not specified (Javascript, HTML5 and Internet Explorer)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, validation, html, getelementbyid

I have this problem of an image rollover javascript not working in Internet Explorer if I don't specify the NAME attribute in the  tag. The other problem is when I do, the HTML5 validator will come up with a message saying "NAME attr is obsolete, use ID instead" which is what I am using with getElementById.

Should I specify a NAME attribute anyway and ignore the error messages or is there a workaround? I don't wish to add extra attributes if I don't have too.

Thanks

Adam

Comment: That shouldn't happen.  Please show us your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't calling `getElementById`; you're writing `document[img_name]`.
Don't.

Answer (score 2):

Check to make sure you do not have duplicate ids. `getElementById` incorrectly gets `name=""` in certain IEs, if there is no element with the id.

Also, make sure the document is not in quirks mode and is in standards mode. `alert( document.compatMode )` and make sure it isnt BackCompat. If it is, use a proper doctype and kill comments/whitespace before doctype.